# Manter parametros do req.body ao mudar de rota

Tags: node.js, express.js

Olá, minha duvida é a seguinte:

Estou usando Express/bodyParser e Nunjucks. Eu submeti um form com o method `POST` a partir da minha rota Raiz '/'.

No form eu tenho dois dados:

- Nome de usuário
- Data de nascimento

No post que faço a submissão do formulário eu consigo fazer uma verificação, de por exemplo, qual a idade do usuário. Se ele for maior eu redireciono para uma rota X se ele for menor de idade eu redireciono para Y.

Minha duvida está justamente nessa rota X e Y. Como eu faço para trazer o nome que o usuário submeteu nessa requisição para uma nova rota?

Eu estou usando *redirect* para mandá-lo para X ou Y.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode repassar os parâmetros da seguinte forma:

```
res.redirect(`/nova_rota?nome=${nome}&data=${data}`);
```

Existem outras formas, basta ler a documentação do redirect

Comment: Daniel, tentei fazer como vc disse ele retorna "name is not defined" quando faz o redirecionamento.
Eu achei que pudesse passar conforme passo variáveis para a view:
res.redirect('/major', { nome: nome});
mas nao é possível.